# Why when incrementing a pointer which received an address of an array behaves differently from the one that has been initialized with the address?

Tags: arrays, pointers, dev-c++

Case 1:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int* exp()
{
    int a[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    
    return a;   
} 

int main()
{   
    int *p=exp();
    
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout<<*p<<" ";
        p++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image: Output for Case:1]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   

    int a[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    
    int *p=a;
    
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout<<*p<<" ";
        p++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image: Output for Case:2]

Why in the above two cases the results are different, although the same address is being returned to the pointer in both cases?
Also, I incremented the pointer correctly (as I think so) therefore it should behave the same in both cases but why this is happening?
Please help me out I am not getting what is actually happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave the function exp() in the first case a is out of scope i.e. the memory originally occupied by this array may already ben used for other purposes. The pointer to this memory location is no longer valid.

Comment: To clarify, the stack allocated array gets destructed right before the function's stack frame is destroyed. Accessing unallocated memory is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Great and to the point explanation @StewartSmith . I got that now.